# Standard input from command line in c with netbeans

Tags: c, input, netbeans, standards

I'm trying to input data from file `sample.txt` into my c program on netbeans.  How can I do that from command line?  I know I should go to 
`File -> Project Properties -> Run -> Run Command.`  But what would I enter for Run Command?

Comment: The question you ask about have *nothing* to do with getting input from a file or command line. It's all about how to run your program. That means the title is wrong and misleading, two of the tags are irrelevant, and the introduction of the question body is irrelevant as well. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Once you get the program to run, and have problems with the actual input, then ask *another* question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set the`OUTPUT_PATH` properly it will be `"${OUTPUT_PATH}" "ARG"`

Comment: yeah it says ${OUTPUT_PATH}.  But I tried adding sample.txt >.  It compiled but didn't run correctly.

Comment: @Alex.: try giving the full path of sample.txt

Comment: hmm tried "/fullpath/sample.txt >". It ran but program won't terminate.  Maybe stuck trying to read sample.txt?  int inputValue;
    int IntArray[50];
    int arraylength = 0;
    while(scanf("%d",&inputValue)!= EOF){
        IntArray[arraylength] = inputValue;
        arraylength++;
    }
    printf("%d", IntArray[0]);

Comment: @Alex.: I guess your question is answered...this is not the scope of this question to look into your probem...

Comment: How would you do it on Unix?

Comment: @Alex.: It's same...you can check their documentation for further information

Comment: To help with your code...I would suggest use `fgets` and then use `strtok` to get the the inetegrs andconvert them to numeric value using `atoi` or `strtol` etc